Android device won’t show up on freshly installed Windows 10. How do I repair this?
I recently installed Windows 10, Build 19045   Version 22h2 64bit, and now the MTP isn’t working (My phone isn't showing up in Windows Explorer)
Usually when I plug in the usb it will immediately open a new file explorer window and show the name of my phone in the file explorer, now it recognizes the usb, but it doesnt show up in file manager.
"Transfer files" mode was selected on the phone
Remedies already I tried:

Ran updates on device manager , it shows the Ss Galaxy ADB incon has the most up to date drivers but there is a , but the MTP icon has a  yellow triangle.
Installed Samsung Galaxy USB drivers from the Samsung website  (going to try to install MTP drivers)
Works fine on my roommates laptop (SO ITS NOT THE PHONE)
4, I tried uninstalling the MTP drivers and rebooting and then restarting it.

What else should I try?
Last month the MTP worked fine on this laptop

Event Viewer Log for MTP
**- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP 
   [ Guid]  {9c205a39-1250-487d-abd7-e831c6290539} 
 
   EventID 400 
 
   Version 0 
 
   Level 4 
 
   Task 0 
 
   Opcode 0 
 
   Keywords 0x4000000000000000 
 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2024-04-03T07:46:10.7736804Z 
 
   EventRecordID 461 
 
   Correlation 
 
  - Execution 
   [ ProcessID]  4 
   [ ThreadID]  4536 
 
   Channel Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP/Configuration 
 
   Computer Sheldon 
 
  - Security 
   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 
 
- EventData 
  DeviceInstanceId USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MS_COMP_MTP&SAMSUNG_Android\6&9715805&2&0000 
  DriverName null 
  ClassGuid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
  DriverDate  
  DriverVersion  
  DriverProvider  
  DriverInbox false 
  DriverSection  
  DriverRank 0x0 
  MatchingDeviceId  
  OutrankedDrivers  
  DeviceUpdated false 
  Status 0x0 
  ParentDeviceInstanceId USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860\ce0717173d9b740805** 


When you open the MTP item with the yellow exclamation mark, what does it tell you? Does Event Viewer tell you anything helpful?

Unlock your phone, click on USB-Connection (in the status area), and choose to share files. This should install the driver.

If that doesn't work, try this driver from Samsung

Have you opened the non working devices and let it search and update the driver after installing the Samsung drivers? Windows often keeps the state even if new drivers were installed and the devices are not fully working.

Yes, as I mentioned in the post, I did let it search for drivers after clicking the update option in device manager,  next suggestion?

I installed that 1.7 usb driver, nothing, next suggestion please

How does one reply to the individual comment, instead of adding a new comment

Also how do I add photos to the comments?

Please read the Help section. You don't add photos in comments. When you are asked for more information by community members, you add that requested information to the question itself, not down here in the comments. Your goal right now is to make your question clear and complete. Info in the comments is often lost or easily overlooked, so don't put info down here yourself. You reply to a specific commentor by typing the @ symbol followed by their name and clicking/tapping the suggested name once that shows. This tags them, it does not mark your reply as being to a specific comment of theirs.

@music2myear. Ok thank you I edited me post to include the event viewer
